# Why do I need to commit ignores under TortoiseSVN?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, commit, ignore, svnignore

When I select ignore on a files under version control it marks the parent directory as changes, then when I then do a commit, it checks in svn:ignore property to the repository, resulting in another revision.

Why do I need to commit the svn:ignore property? Is this a TortoiseSVN issue or just the way SVN works?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's the way SVN works.

More information here:

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.props.html#svn.advanced.props.workflow

Quote from that page:

> As with file contents, your property
>   changes are local modifications, made
>   permanent only when you commit them to
>   the repository with svn commit.

Answer (score 6):

The idea is that, if you ignore a file, others will want to ignore the same file.  Basically, what this means is that, system-wide, individuals will be ignoring the same files resulting in a more consistent development environment (and a cleaner repository as developers won't check in personal files, etc that are generated by IDEs, their testing files, etc).

Answer (score 3):

That's the way SVN works.  When you commit an ignore, it automatically ignores that same file for others as well.